# C++ implementation of the Command Pattern

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns

Below is a C++ implementation of the Command Pattern. I wrote three receivers that carry out the intended action (making a sound) differently. I also wrote command and invoking classes. I saw no need to write a client class, so `main()` is the client.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// receivers

class Cow {
public:
    void moo() {
        std::cout << "Cow says moo!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Dog {
    std::string name;
public:
    Dog(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}

    void makeSound() {
        std::cout << name + " barks!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Car {
    bool engineOn;
public:
    Car() : engineOn(false) {};

    void turnCarOn() {
        engineOn = true;
    }

    void revEngine() {
        if (engineOn) {
            std::cout << "Vroom, vroom, vroom!" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Silence!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

// commands

class Command {
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class CowCommand : public Command {
    Cow cow;
public:
    CowCommand(Cow cow) : cow(cow) {}

    void execute() {
        cow.moo();
    }
};

class DogCommand : public Command {
    Dog dog;
public:
    DogCommand(Dog dog) : dog(dog) {}

    void execute() {
        dog.makeSound();
    }
};

class CarCommand : public Command {
    Car car;
public:
    CarCommand(Car car) : car(car) {}

    void execute() {
        car.turnCarOn();
        car.revEngine();
    }
};

// invoker

class PlatoSays {
    Command* ptr_command;
public:
    PlatoSays() : ptr_command(nullptr) {}

    void setCommand(Command* ptr_cmd) {
        ptr_command = ptr_cmd;
    }

    void invokeCommand() {
        if (ptr_command) {
            std::cout << "Plato says: ";
            ptr_command->execute();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Plato has nothing to say!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

// client

int main() {
    PlatoSays plato;

    plato.setCommand(new CowCommand(Cow()));
    plato.invokeCommand();

    plato.setCommand(new DogCommand(Dog("Lucky")));
    plato.invokeCommand();

    plato.setCommand(new CarCommand(Car()));
    plato.invokeCommand();

    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Virtual Destructor

If a class has virtual methods it should also have a virtual destructor. Now this is only important if you destroy a class from a pointer to the base class. Since your code leaks all the objects it will not hurt you (Note: I am being facetious). Both leaking and incorrectly destroying objects is a big deal. This is after all not **C** and thus we like to actually write working programs.

```
class Command {
public:
    virtual ~Command() {}      // Declare a virtual destuctor in
                               // the base class. All derived types
                               // will inherit a virtual destructor.
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};
```

#### Override Specifier

In C++11 we added the `override` specifier. You are supposed to use this to make virtual functions you are overriding. It provides a nice safety blanket, if somebody in the future changes the virtual function definition then the `override` specifier in your class will cause an error if you have not changed the definition in your class to match.

```
class CowCommand : public Command {
    Cow cow;
public:
    CowCommand(Cow cow) : cow(cow) {}

    void execute() override {   // Add override here.
        cow.moo(); 
    }
};
```

#### Don't pass by value (Pass by const ref as a first default).

If you pass by value you are causing a copy of the object. This may be unnecessarily expensive. Pass by const reference. If you need to then you can make a copy before using.

Alternatively you can pass by R-Value reference and move the object in the methods.

```
    Cow cow;
public:
    // You make two copies of cow here.
    CowCommand(Cow cow)       // A copy is made to pass it to the method.
        : cow(cow)            // A second copy is made passing while
                              // creating the local `cow` object.
    {}


    // I would have done this:
    CowCommand(Cow const& cow)   // Pass a normal reference
        : cow(cow)               // Now make a copy (only 1 copy)
    {}
    CowCommand(Cow&& cow)        // Pass an r-value reference
        : cow(std::move(cow))    // Move the object into cow.
    {}
```

#### Don't pass pointers

A pointer has no concept of ownership. Ownership decides who is supposed to delete the object. If I don't know who is supposed to delete I may accidentally delete something that is not dynamic or if I don't delete something I am supposed to then I leak an object.

The idea is that public interfaces should pass things around in a way that ownership of the object is clear (private and internal methods can use pointers for efficiency).

This public function passes a pointer.

```
void setCommand(Command* ptr_cmd) {
    ptr_command = ptr_cmd;
}
```

Internally you store it as a pointer. But you don't take ownership (i.e. you don't call delete on the pointer in the destructor). So this object can easily be used incorrectly.

```
{
    PlatoSays  plato;
    plato.setCommand(new LokiCommand);
}
```

Here I have created a dynamic object and passed in it `setCommand()` (which has the only copy of this pointer. At the end of scope the `LokiCommand` object is leaked.

If you are not going to take ownership then pass by reference. This indicates to the method you can have a link to my object but I will delete it (not you).

```
void setCommand(Command& ptr_cmd) {
    ptr_command = &ptr_cmd;   // Its OK to store a pointer to the object
                              // Just mean Plato has to be created first
                              // and destroyed last.
}
```

Note: If you do want to pass ownership. Then wrap your pointer in a smart pointer. This will take care of the ownership.

```
class PlatoSays {
    std::unique_ptr<Command> ptr_command;
public:
    void setCommand(std::unique_ptr<Command>&& ptr_cmd) {
        ptr_command = std::move(ptr_cmd);
    }

    // Notice the usage of a unique_ptr is exactly the same as the
    // usage for a normal pointer. The only difference is that it
    // Correctly initializes itself (so you don't need a constructor)
    // And when updating it you need to use `std::move()`
    void invokeCommand() {
        if (ptr_command) {
            std::cout << "Plato says: ";
            ptr_command->execute();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Plato has nothing to say!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

#### Leaks in your program.

And here we see the exact problem with pointers.

```
plato.setCommand(new CowCommand(Cow()));
plato.invokeCommand();

plato.setCommand(new DogCommand(Dog("Lucky")));
plato.invokeCommand();

plato.setCommand(new CarCommand(Car()));
plato.invokeCommand();
```

All three of these objects are leaked.

Use when ownership **is not** transferred:

```
PlatoSays plato;
CowCommand   cow(Cow());
DogCommand   dog(Dog("Lucky");
CarCommand   car(Car());

plato.setCommand(cow);
plato.invokeCommand();

plato.setCommand(dog);
plato.invokeCommand();

plato.setCommand(car);
plato.invokeCommand();
```

Use when ownership **is** transferred:

```
PlatoSays plato;
plato.setCommand(std::unique_ptr<Command>(new CowCommand(Cow()));
plato.invokeCommand();

plato.setCommand(std::unique_ptr<Command>(new DogCommand(Dog("Lucky"))));
plato.invokeCommand();

plato.setCommand(std::unique_ptr<Command>(new CarCommand(Car())));
plato.invokeCommand();
```

#### Prefer `"\n"` over `std::endl`

The only difference is that `std::endl` flushes the stream. Manual programmer flushing is the usually non optimal and the cause of most slow downs when comparing C++ code to C code speed.